# Initializing classes, in python

Tags: python, class

I was trying to convert some python code, which was not written using classes, to use classes. This was just a part of understanding classes more. The code is as following :

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for i in args:
            try:
                <code>
            except <Exception>:
                print("Messages...")
                exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = myClass()
```

I know that the `__init__` method will get automatically run once `myClass()` is called, but I'm not sure how to deal with the *args, since when I run this code, I get:

```
TypeError: 'myClass' object is not callable
```

I can write another function which does what I want and call it as `start.<func>`, but I want to put this in `__init__`. Is this something bad to do or perfectly normal ? How would I be able to do it?

Comment: Show the full traceback. The line that causes this error is not included in the code you posted here.

Comment: Tested your code and it runs fine. Where do you exactly have this exception?

Comment: Same for me.  For 2.7.3 code above runs fine.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not the `*args`. The issue is that somewhere in your code you are trying to treat an instance of `myClass` as callable. For example, you might have something like:

```
start = myClass()
start()
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, i missed to add start() at the end.

Comment: Yes, thats my mistake, after removing 'start()'. its working, but hitting on another error.. I'll check and update.

Comment: @vimal: If it's a different problem, please post a separate question.